# Javascript Date Validation (Range)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is it possible through Jquery/Javascript that I can validate a date with the following conditions

> example date : 10/10/2011
>
> Conditions : Not in the past (accept
>   today onwards) Not more than 18 months
>   (this can be variable)

Because the ways I found out was

```
var e = new Date();                  
Alert(e.getMonth() + 2);
```

but this is not what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

you might want to have a look at date.js

it's a great library for manipulating dates in javascript.

http://www.datejs.com/

here's the documentation:

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation

it can also do the comparisons for you!

have a look at Date.compare and Date.addMonths

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JQuery's Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), it has validation included and is pretty nice overall.

Comment: I am using the datepicker but I am building a framework and am very tight of what to use.. So there is no way to verify this client side?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this:

```
var toValidate = new Date('10/10/2011');
var months = 18;

var now = new Date();
var minDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var maxDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + months, now.getDate());

var valid = minDate < toValidate && toValidate < maxDate;
```

Comment: You should set 'minDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);' to allow a date today but before now.

Comment: Indeed, good catch, was editing it the minute you commented :)

Comment: Note: as far as I know, creating a date from a string will evaluate using the current locale's date format. That is, a date like "10/06/2011" will be taken as June 10 in Australia (and many other countries), but as October 6 in the US.